# SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: 2013

I am trying to install the SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 on a Windows 7 SP1 machine. I am able to create the CM and CD Databases successfully through PowerShell, however, when I start installing Content Manager, it says the OS is not supported. I verified the list of supported OS, please refer below screen shots. Is it something very basic I am missing out there. Any help will be appreciated.

**Supported OS as in the Pre-Requisite Manual:**

[image]

**My Windows (I checked and all Windows Updates are up to date):**

[image]

**The Error while executing CM setup:**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tridion Content Manager **Server** is not supported on Windows 7, only on a Windows Server OS. The list of supported OS you're looking at is for the Tridion Content Manager **Client** (Content Manager Explorer and Experience Manager).

Comment: oops, my bad!! So this is the basic mistake I was doing...Thanks Nuno.